# Comparar valores entre un input y un array

Tags: javascript, array, input

Estoy creando un input que toma los valores de un array y los compara con el valor del mismo, lo que me gustaria hacer es que en caso de que los resultados empiecen con la misma letra los muestre a partir de un evento on keyup, hasta ahora tengo esto:

```js
let valorBusqueda = document.querySelector('#valor');
let opcBusqueda = document.querySelector('.opc-busqueda');

//Event Listener
valorBusqueda.addEventListener('keyup', keyUpCampo);


//Funciones
function keyUpCampo() {    
  
    //Muestra el menu de sugerencias
    opcBusqueda.style = "display: flex";  
    sendToPage();    
}

var sendToPage = function () {
  //Get the input value by finding the element by its ID
  let busqueda = document.getElementById('valor').value;


  //Check if the value is in the array
  var sugerencias = ['marvel', 'futbol','goku ssj','falafel','robocop', 'rick', 'morty', 'x-men', 'starwars', 'goku', 'bulma', 'vegeta', 'simpsons', 'homer', 'cartoon'];
 
  for (k in sugerencias) {
    if (busqueda.includes(sugerencias[k])) {
      let input = document.createElement("INPUT");
      input.setAttribute('type','button');
      input.setAttribute('value',`${sugerencias[k]}`)
      opcBusqueda.appendChild(input) 
    } 
    
  }   

}
```

```html
   
<body>
    <div class="busqueda">        
        <div class="inputs">
            <input id="valor" type="text" placeholder=" Busca hashgtags, temas, busca lo que quieras.."></div>
    </div>    
    
    <div class="opc-busqueda" style="display: none;"></div>
   
</body>
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando el `includes()` al revez.  La forma correcta es `if (sugerencias[k].includes(busqueda)) {`:

```js
let valorBusqueda = document.querySelector('#valor');
let opcBusqueda = document.querySelector('.opc-busqueda');

//Event Listener
valorBusqueda.addEventListener('keyup', keyUpCampo);


//Funciones
function keyUpCampo() {    
  
    //Muestra el menu de sugerencias
    opcBusqueda.style = "display: flex";  
    sendToPage();    
}

var sendToPage = function () {
  //Get the input value by finding the element by its ID
  let busqueda = document.getElementById('valor').value;


  //Check if the value is in the array
  var sugerencias = ['marvel', 'futbol','goku ssj','falafel','robocop', 'rick', 'morty', 'x-men', 'starwars', 'goku', 'bulma', 'vegeta', 'simpsons', 'homer', 'cartoon'];
 
  for (k in sugerencias) {
    if (sugerencias[k].includes(busqueda)) {
      let input = document.createElement("INPUT");
      input.setAttribute('type','button');
      input.setAttribute('value',`${sugerencias[k]}`)
      opcBusqueda.appendChild(input) 
    } 
    
  }   

}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="busqueda">        
        <div class="inputs">
            <input id="valor" type="text" placeholder=" Busca hashgtags, temas, busca lo que quieras.."></div>
    </div>    
    
    <div class="opc-busqueda" style="display: none;"></div>
   
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aca pude lograr el tipo de input con la comparacion que queria, lo unico que me faltaria seria eliminar los resultados a medida que se va escribiendo y coincide

```js
//Variables

let valorBusqueda = document.querySelector('#valor');
let opcBusqueda = document.querySelector('.opc-busqueda');



//Event Listener

valorBusqueda.addEventListener('keyup', keyUpCampo);



//Funciones

function keyUpCampo() {    
  
    //Muestra el menu de sugerencias
    opcBusqueda.style = "display: flex; flex-direction:column; width:165px";  
  
    sendToPage();
    
}




var sendToPage = function () {
  //Get the input value by finding the element by its ID
  let busqueda = document.getElementById('valor').value;


  //Check if the value is in the array
  var sugerencias = ['marvel','maravilloso', 'futbol','goku ssj','falafel','robocop', 'rick','ricardo', 'morty', 'x-men', 'starwars', 'goku', 'bulma', 'vegeta', 'simpsons', 'homer', 'cartoon'];
  var coincidencias =[]
  for (indice in sugerencias) {

    let lSug = sugerencias[indice].charAt();

    if (lSug.includes(busqueda.charAt())) {
        
       coincidencias.push(sugerencias[indice]);

        opcBusqueda.innerHTML =  `<input type="button" value=${coincidencias[0]} >
                                  <input type="button" value=${coincidencias[1]} >
                                  <input type="button" value=${coincidencias[2]} >      
      `        
    }   
    
  } 

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="busqueda">        
        <div class="inputs">
            <input id="valor" type="text" placeholder=" Busca hashgtags, temas, busca lo que quieras..">
            
        </div>
    </div>    
    
    <div class="opc-busqueda" style="display: none;">
       
    </div>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```